# Regular expression to get class name

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write some regular expression to only get the classes in an HTML tag.

E.g.

```
<h1 class="big blue" id="testing"> some text </h1>
```

I want the regular expression to return big blue. I've been trying to do that but it includes the id as well:

Regular expression: `<(.+)?class=\s*"(.+)?">`
Testing example: `<h1 class="big blue" id="testing"> some text </h1>`

https://regex101.com/r/0weyDs/2

Comment: Please don't use regex for html: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @sshashank124 the reason that I'm doing it is that the HTML is stored in a db as a text. So when I get it from the db, I want to do some regex on it.

Comment: Use an html parser

Comment: @sshashank124 thanks for your suggestion. But, how can I make changes to that HTML if it gets parsed? Can you please refer me to an article or something that you might have read about it? Thanks again

Comment: I have no idea which language you are using since you haven't included a tag for that. But for python, there is the [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) package

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/372239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am using JavaScript to do it)

If you are certain there is no `"` inside the class name of `class="abc xyz"`, then you can use

```
/<(.+?)class=\s*"([^"]*?)"/g
```

Example:

```
([...'<h1 class="big blue" id="testing"> some text </h1><div id="foo" class="blue danube page-title"> some text </div><span class=""></span>'
  .matchAll(/<(.+?)class=\s*"([^"]*?)"/g)].map(arr => arr[2]))
```

would give

```
["big blue", "blue danube page-title", ""]
```

One bug about non-greedy: it is `.+?` and if you have `(.+)?` it means match as much as possible and then "optional".

The other concern is you probably want to match `class=""` as `""`, so it'd be `[^"]*` rather than `[^"]+`

One issue with your orignail regex is that you match the ending `>`, so it has to match to the end even if you say non-greedy.  You can see https://regex101.com/r/0weyDs/3  for

```
<(.+?)class=\s*"(.+?)"
```

or https://regex101.com/r/0weyDs/4 for the first regex in the answer.